# Subscribe method get call multiple times Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, observable, angular2-routing, subscribe

I have one method subscribed in `ngOnInit` of controller.ts. From the view, there is an option to select the different user from listing which redirects to the same page just ID from URL gets changed. Hence `ngOnInit` gets invoked multiple times. Hence method gets subscribed multiple times. A number of times we select different users method get invoked for each number of a member selected i.e. if we select 3 users one after another route gets changed 3 times hence method gets invoked 3 times when observable gets the result.But if we refresh the page everything works fine. but if I used unsubscribe in `ngDestroy` then it won't get subscribed again in `ngOnInit`. Is any solution for this.

```
 ngOnInit() { 
    this._myService.detailsReceived.subscribe((obj: details) => 
       {console.log(obj.text)}
    );
 }
```

the route change on same page is

```
this.route.navigate(['user-home', userid]);
```

I require this method to keep subscribed until user gets logout, hence canonot use `subscribe.Take(1)`

Comment: Woult it not make sence to put this logic outside of your multiple time called componentent and put it into an extra service which is then only injected on time on the top level file?
But don't subscribe inside a Service - the subscription will never be stopped - Subscribe to it in your top level component from which you navigate to all components.

Comment: The component is my main component but as I fetched info of other user, I passed parameter Id through route hence component gets refreshed again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> but if I used unsubscribe in ngDestroy then it won't get subscribed again in ngOnInit

From comments:

> `ngOnDestroy() { this._myService.detailsReceived.unsubscribe(); }` I used this. Is it wrong way to unsubscribe?

You are not unsubscribing correctly. You have to unsubscribe from the `Subscription`, **not** the `Observable`. Unsubscribing to the observable causes exactly that behavior that you described.

```
// import 
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

///////

// In the component
detailRecivedSubscription: Subscription;
ngOnInit() { 
    this.detailRecivedSubscription = this._myService.detailsReceived.subscribe((obj: details) => 
       {console.log(obj.text)}
    );
}
ngOnDestroy() { 
    this.detailRecivedSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

---

*Also in this scenario it might also make more sense to subscribe to this service in the/a root level component.*

Comment: ngOnDestroy() { 
   this._myService.detailsReceived.unsubscribe();
}

I used this. Is it wrong way to unsubscribe?

Comment: @Amey - That is wrong. See the code in my answer, that is how you should unsubscribe.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, now its working fine without error. Way of unscibed works finely. I used it before navigate and then works fine.